# PHP form validation that includes SUBMIT button

Tags: php

I have been trying to find a way to validate email in my PHP code. I can only give you parts of my code cause it is really long. What I want to do is to have a person enter their email address by clicking a submit button and if they have entered their email in an unacceptable format, an error message appears. But my problem is: how can I COMBINE a  tag WITH "function validate email($field)"? In other words, I know how to combine (PART A) and (PART B), that is easy enough. But what I really want to do is combine (PART B) with (PART C) and not use (PART A) at all. Is that possible? Can I somehow include "isset" inside "function validate email($field)"? I must have a submit button and I must be able to validate the email.

```
     (PART A)       <?php //formtest2.php
                       if (isset($_POST['email'])) $email = $_POST['email'];
                         else $email = "(Not entered)";
                     ?>


     (PART B)      <?php  
                   function validate_email($field)
                    {
                      if ($field == "") return "No email was entered<br>";
                        else if (!((strpos($field, ".") > 0) &&
                          (strpos($field, "@") > 0)) ||
                             preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/", $field))
                              return "The email address is invalid<br>";
                                return "";
                     }
                     ?>


      (PART C)         <body>
                          Your email is: $email<br>
                            <form method="post"  action="brownuniversity.php">
                               What is your email address?
                                  <input type="text"  name="email">
                                       <input type="submit">
                            </form>
                         </body>
```

Comment: Seems like the form is posting to brownuniversity.php instead of formtest2.php. I think you have the right validation in formtest2.php, if you were to call validate_email from formtest2.php... You just need to post to the right file.

Comment: Yes, that was an oversight, but I have been posting to brownuniversity.php -- that is not the problem. My problem is how to combine the different parts and come up with a solution.

Comment: Well, if you are posting to the right page, just call validate_email from brownuniversity.php (maybe inside the else statement). Then, if the validate_email returns something other than "" you know there is an error, you could either redirect back to the page and display an error, or do something else.

Comment: The OP needs a better regx the current one will match all kinds of things that are not email and it only looks at a single character ie no + on the end.

Comment: The one I gave you requires at a minimum that they enter "a@b.c" as the input.  I also updated the answer, and added isset and trim, trim is always a good idea on something a user might paste into a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi first of all your gonna want to change this whole thing,

```
 function validate_email($field)
                    {
                      if ($field == "") return "No email was entered<br>";
                        else if (!((strpos($field, ".") > 0) &&
                          (strpos($field, "@") > 0)) ||
                             preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/", $field))
                              return "The email address is invalid<br>";
                                return "";
                     }
```

To this little bit.

```
function validate_email( $field ){
    if (preg_match("/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/", $field)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You'll have to do the error messages elsewhere, but this is more portable. ( and I give you a much better Regx for emails ), now you can just do this

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = trim( $_POST['email'] ); //remove any whitespaces from pasting email.
    if(validate_email($email)){
    //send mail or whatever

    }else{
    //show errors

    }
}
```

You will still have to check if isset( $_POST['email'] inside the validation isn't really the place to check for it, it should only be concerned with if the data is valid or not, not if there is no data.  Also you'll need to check that the form was posted anyway before calling the function and the isset serves both these needs.  I updated the answer, you don't really need a validation message on the case that it is not set, because if that is the case they didnt submit the form, it should always be set on form submission.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thank you kindly for pointing out my regex mistake and for showing me a solution !

Comment: Sure I been using this regx for email for like a year or so.  Looking at it now though I could streamline it a bit.